# How to create a layout of my college classrooms

Tags: javascript, android, html

I want to make an app exactly like movie apps which show which of the seats are taken. Instead replacing seats by classrooms, so that I can easily figure out which classes are empty and which classes are occupied.

Comment: looks more like a client's request to a developper than a SO question.. you know, clients usually pay for tasks. Come on, show us at least that you tried something!

Comment: https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/SeatBookingRecyclerView

Comment: I haven't worked on this yet ..it's just an idea. I am not able to understand how to start. If you give me a basic idea, that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: even for that, your question is too vague, don't ask us to guess what you want.. is it a web page (js and html tags) or an android layout (android tag)? you have to be much more precise

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow, is not a place where you can ask for people to do the code for you.
Please read the help center on asking questions
https://stackoverflow.com/help

People are down-voting you because you need to show what you have learnt or showing that you have tried to at least to do your own research, most questions are already asked on this huge community.

If you attempt or edit your question to show some sort of existing google or fix up your question, people will help it.